# Creating a view off another view

Tags: mysql, view

I currently have a view called `v_testhorses` which pulls data from `Horses` and `Results`. It has the following values -

```
HID|HName|YOB|Gender|Sire|Dam|OName|Stable|LTE|Year
```

Where `LTE` = the sum of the `earnings` field from `Results` and `Year` = an individual column created for each year

(for example, if Horse B showed in 2012 and 2011, there'd be only columns for those two years with separate LTEs for each year)

I'm trying to create a view just using the `Sire` field, while taking these others things into consideration. Ideally it'd look like this -

```
HID|HName|ProgenyEarnings|Year
```

Where `HName` in this case is based off `Sire` and `ProgenyEarnings` is the sum of `LTE` of all horses with that `Sire`. It'd be a way to look at all horses in `v_testhorses` and "assign" them to a sire, who is also in the `v_testhorses` database. It'd be the easiest way to decide who was the highest grossing sire in each year based off their progeny.

I hope this makes sense!
I've been trying the `WHERE HName=Sire` as a clause and it just gives me an empty view.

Comment: How can the same view have different years for each horse? A view can't create columns dynamically, that can only be done with dynamic SQL in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the view with itself to relate the progeny to its sire:

```
SELECT h1.HID, h1.HName, SUM(h2.LTE) AS ProgenyEarnings, h1.Year
FROM v_testhorses AS h1
JOIN v_testhorses AS h2 ON h1.HName = h2.Sire
GROUP BY h1.HID
```

Comment: That lead to the following error: 1104 - The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay

Comment: You might need to use temporary tables instead of views for this.

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping for something I could call up using PHP on my website

Comment: You can create temporary tables using PHP.

Comment: In this answer h1.HName and h1.year can be random values (read wrong values) if h1.HID isn't a unique or primary key.. because h1.HName and h1.Year arn't named within the GROUP BY

Comment: @RaymondNijland I assumed `HID` is the primary key. Usually columns named ID are the primary key.